# SublimeText - add Comments *about* code?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I was wondering if there's a way, native or via plug-in, that allows me to add comments to my code.

I do *not* mean a code comment, using python as an example:

```
def some_function():
    my_variable = 123 
    my_array = [123,345,345]
    #this next line will do some math
    final_val = 1+2
```

I mean a comment that lets me expand on an item.  For instance, I'm learning `matplotlib` and would like to put in a comment about the `xycoords`, what the different types can be.

Currently, it's clunky and takes up a ton of lines:

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a way to, for instance, highlight `xycoords` then add a comment to that, so when I mouseover it, a comment pops up showing that info I have above...

Using Word to show a clunky example:

[image]

Edit: to be clear, I just need these comments available in Sublime. They're  not intended to be part of the published/complete application. It's just for me while I program in SublimeText

Comment: You're asking it there is a way to add metadata, however metadata support is a function of the file format more than the application itself. If it is to be part of the application there will need to be additional files or a database of some sort and functions that relate specific comments to specific locations in specific files. In other words, probably not.

Comment: @music2myear - I'm asking how to add a note for me, the programmer, in Sublime.  In the application, when published online let's say, I don't want that comment there. It's just for me as I learn.  Is that metadata?  Basically, instead of keeping going to Google or a webpage to review the info, I'd like to just add a comment in Sublime-Text that I can refer to instead.

Comment: Then you're looking for a database of comments and some system to relate the comments to the files/code. Either there is a plugin that does this or there isn't. Considering most people just use regular inline comments in the code for this sort of thing, I'd guess there may not be much demand for such a tool, and therefore a rather low chance of it existing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [Sublime Text documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/comments.html), it seems that this kind of behavior is not supported. However, an alternative could be to install a package like [Fold Comments](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fold%20Comments) that allow you to collapse multiline comments within your code.